# htaccess - Wildcard subdomains to subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

So the idea is that I have:

```
domain.com/.subdomains/domain1 (2,3,4,etc)
```

And I want to map:

```
domain1.domain.com -> domain.com/.subdomains/domain1/
domain2.domain.com -> domain.com/.subdomains/domain2/
```

But I want it to ignore "www"

I'm doing this semi-successfully with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/.subdomains/%1/$1 [NC,QSA,L,P]
```

There are two problems:

1) It's not ignoring the "www"

2) When I go to URL:

```
http://domain3.domain.com/deep/subfolder/here/index.html
```

it redirects me to:

```
http://domain.com/.subdomains/domain3/deep/subfolder/here/index.html
```

I've been trying to find answers, but I cannot find anyone else having this problem.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay, seems that I can't use the http, but if I change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/.subdomains/%1/$1 [NC,QSA,L,P]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.subdomains/%1/$1 [NC,QSA,L,P]
```

It goes to a weird redirect loop

Comment: Did you use a shared IP address or dedicated IP address. I have been trying to get this to work on my go daddy but it seems the wildcard domain itself is not active. I already added it in the DNS too. But single sub domains work. Wildcards * don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# MAGIC
RewriteCond $1 !/$
RewriteCond $1 !\.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
# //MAGIC

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.subdomains/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.subdomains/%1/$1 [L]
```

I pretty much understand rest of the code, except the magic part - somehow it fixes this bug:

```
http://domain3.domain.com/deep/subfolder/here/index.html
```

To

```
http://domain.com/.subdomains/domain3/deep/subfolder/here/index.html
```

Right now that does not happen, thanks to the MAGIC... I wish I knew why it worked.